# Cannot remove OneNote from Greenshot

Tags: ini

Something pretty strange is happening.

In %appdata%\greenshot\Greenshot.ini

I have :

```
ExcludeDestinations=OneNote
```

and OneNote still shows on the list?

I also tried with a 
 C:\Program Files\Greenshot\greenshot-fixed.ini

containing this line, nothing works. OneNote always shows. It's crucial for me to disable it since it doesn't work at the moment even with latest Greenshot release (1.2.9.129 or new 1.2.10.3-RC1)

If i add for example :

```
ExcludeDestinations=OneNote,Outlook,Word
```

Outlook and Word disappear from the destination list but OneNote still shows...however i'm clearly using the proper name as listed here :

http://getgreenshot.org/faq/how-remove-plugins-or-destinations-from-greenshot/

Thank you for you time!

Comment: for me it actually gets taken off the list .....  some kind of conspiracy :-p

Comment: the tool development page acknowledges the behavior that OneNote is specifically protected for no particular reason ...  https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/SUPPORT-198?oldIssueView=true

Answer (score 1):

To remove the OneNote I can recommend excluding plugins as well. 
Just came across the same issue and this line solved my problem:

```
ExcludePlugins=Office Plugin
```

You can try as well other plugins that are listed in the link you found as well:

http://getgreenshot.org/faq/how-remove-plugins-or-destinations-from-greenshot/

Comment: This is to exclude ALL office destinations but in our situation we need to keep everything Office related (word, Outlook,etc.) EXCEPT OneNote. So it's not possible then? This is clearly a bug from Greenshot team. I opened a ticket but they don't seem to read them: https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/SUPPORT-198

Comment: this works for me to exclude all of Office, which is good for me right now.  I understand it does not work for the OP or others who want to remove only OneNote.   Maybe fork the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Greenshot "Preferences..." in the icons menu.
2. Go to the "Plugins" tab in the "Settings" window.
3. Read the DLL Path of the Office Plugin (it is the same for all the default installations)

[image]

4. Close the Greenshot application via "Exit" in the icons menu.
5. Navigate to the (c:) drive location/path of the Plugin

Mine was **C:\Program Files\Greenshot\Plugins**

6. With the Applicaiton closed, you can delete the Plugin folder for "Office" and for save keeps, create a copy of it and save a zipped version in your Documents/Downlaods folder etc.

[image]

7. When you return the plugins will be removed as you active screen capturing options

[image]